# Combine files on commit in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, filter, hook

I've got a project with 2 files I want to source-control using Mercurial:

- A SCX-File which is a binary (database) file
- A SCT-File which is a text file

My filter:

```
[encode]
**.scx = tempfile: sccxml INFILE OUTFILE 0
[decode]
**.scx = tempfile: sccxml INFILE OUTFILE 1
```

Problem

- sccxml only receives the path to the SCX-File
- The SCX-File can not be converted to a text-file without the corresponding SCT-File

Workarounds

- Is it possible to combine the files before the filter runs?
- Is it possible to pass both file's paths to sccxml-Converter?

**UPDATE:**

No, I'm using not using the Win32Text extension. 
The SccXml-Executable needs both an SCT-File and an SCX-File as parameter to convert them to a Text-File (the text-representations of both files get tar'ed into one file).

I Want To have the binary files as Text-File in the Repo, to get meaningful diffs. I am currently trying to achieve this using a precommit hook.

Comment: your question seems a bit unclear. Can you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: Are you using the deprecated [Win32Text](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Win32TextExtension) extension? It's probably not a good idea. Please describe what exactly you want to do with the files first, then we'll figure out a solution.

Comment: updated my post, hope you can help me now